# Atomically replace symlink with the folder it points to

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I have a symlink that points to a directory mounted via network file system like so:

```
2023 -> /mnt/bulk013/obs_data_archive/metwatch/2023/
```

now I want to replace the symlink with the folder that it points to in a fashion that doesn't disturb a productive application that frequently reads from this directory (atomically). This meant in my case first copying all the data to my local harddrive (where the folder `2023` lives). I did so and used a temporary directory to store the files:

```
2023.tmp/
```

So now the question is, how can I atomically switch the symlink with the actual folder, so that the folder then has the name `2023`?

```
2023 -> /mnt/bulk013/obs_data_archive/metwatch/2023/   # remove this
2023.tmp/  # and replaced with this (renamed to 2023)
```

Comment: Seems like your goal is to avoid a network hop, so could you just use `ln -sf 2023.tmp 2023`?

Comment: @cmbuckley It is and I thought about this, but ain't it ugly! haha

Comment: I’ve seen uglier! If you regularly point the path at a different directory of contents, then a symlink is a fairly neat way to do this and atomically switch. If it’s a one-off, it really depends on the robustness of the application and how it opens files.

Comment: Deos https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5093/how-does-one-atomically-change-a-symlink-to-a-directory-in-busybox answer your quesiton? You want to replace symlink with directory or symlink with different symlink? First one is not possible atomically, second one is.

Comment: Oh, I had mistakenly thought `ln -sf` would be atomic, but creating a second symlink and using `mv -T` seems to be the only option

Answer (score 1):

In brief notation, if we have:

```
link -> dir/
```

and want to swizzle this to become:

```
link/
```

It would **seem** that what we want is to execute the system call `rename("dir", "link/")`.

Unfortunately, that refuses to work on Linux with an `errno` of 20 (`ENOTDIR`). This is [documented](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html) for `rename` by POSIX: one of the reasons `rename` can return `ENOTDIR` is:

> *the old argument names a directory and the new argument names a non-directory file*

Looks like there may not be a way to do this; it has to be done in two operations, requiring the accessing application to be suspended.

If the application consists of a small number of processes, you may be able to `kill -STOP` them all, do the swizzle, and then `kill -CONT`. To a stopped process, the operation will appear atomic.

Comment: Thanks, that last hint was actually gold, I didn't think of that. Indeed usually it's only one process in our system that uses these resources so I'll try that.

Comment: @glades Even if it is several processes, the approach should work. It's the same basic idea as in "stop-the-world" multithreaded garbage collection.